# How to make scp go faster?

Tags: networking, scp

I use the following command to transfer files across my home network (when I have to transfer a lot of files, I usually archive them with the `tar` utility):

```
scp -c blowfish [FILE] [USER]@[ADDRESS]:[PATH]
```

It takes about 25 minutes to send 500 Mb of data to another computer. The average speed is at about 600 KB/s. I think there absolutely must be a way to make the process go faster because I don't believe that I'm able to pull a 1 Gb file comfortably off the Web in less than 10 minutes, but I can't get a 500 Mb file sent across the network in less that time.

Comment: You can use `rsync` to transfer data  much more fast than `scp`  syntax is quite the same `rsync -avP [FILE] [USER]@[ADDRESS]:[PATH]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. Experiment with a different cipher
2. Use 'on the fly' compression

**1. Experiment with a different cipher:**

One idea is to test the various ciphers which are available through `scp` and try to determine which is the fastest for you. (The idea behind this is that it is the encryption of your data that is taking up the time.) Find the available ciphers by running the following:

```
andrew@athens:~$ ssh -Q cipher
3des-cbc
blowfish-cbc
cast128-cbc
arcfour
arcfour128
arcfour256
aes128-cbc
aes192-cbc
aes256-cbc
rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
aes128-ctr
aes192-ctr
aes256-ctr
aes128-gcm@openssh.com
aes256-gcm@openssh.com
chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
andrew@athens:~$
```

This shows available ciphers on a default Xenial Xerus installation and can be added in using the syntax you have already suggested:

```
scp -c <cipher> [FILE] [USER]@[ADDRESS]:[PATH]
```

This option is passed directly to `ssh` hence testing `ssh` itself for the available ciphers. Hopefully you can find a cipher that will allow an increase in your transfer speed, when you have found this cipher you can place it in `~/.ssh/config` rather than typing it in each time...

**2. Use 'on the fly' compression:**

`scp` is able to compress your transfers 'on the fly' meaning that the compressions is only used during transfer and will not be seen at either the host or remote ends. Add this in using the `-C` option:

```
scp -c <cipher> -C [FILE] [USER]@[ADDRESS]:[PATH]
```

Here is an example on my own system:

```
debug1: compress outgoing: raw data 365865, compressed 150118, factor 0.41
debug1: compress incoming: raw data 150118, compressed 365865, factor 2.44
```

The compression level is the same as the one used for `gzip` and if you really wish to experiment you can use the 'CompressionLevel' option which varies from 1-9, 1 being the fastest compression, 9 being the slowest with best compression and 6 being the default. This can be set in `~/.ssh/config`as follows:

```
Host *
Compression yes
CompressionLevel 9
```

Bear in mind that this sets high compression for *all* `scp / ssh` transfers, it can be set for individual hosts if you wish...

Use the `-v` option to investigate the effects of any changes you make. You will note with experimentation that different data will have different compression ratios.

Comment: I did a bunch of experimenting [one time](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2271473&p=13255758#post13255758) and found using the arcfour cipher made the biggest improvement (double) for my situation.

Comment: Or since this is on a home network where you presumably don't need to worry about anyone intercepting the traffic, use no encryption at all.